# Chrome Extension postMessage & Listener

Tags: javascript, dom, events, google-chrome-extension, event-handling

I am injecting a script in website DOM from my extension. The script accesses the DOM object & returns using postMessage(). I then listen to this in content.js & get the object. There's a function which injects these scripts in DOM & expects the object to return. This function gets called 5 times & expects 5 different objects. The 1st call gets executed successfully & returns object1 in addListener. But after that the listener waits to execute all the 4 scripts & holds the object in postMessage. Once entire extension is loaded then the addEventListener gets called in the end & then it returns all 4 remaining objects.

Why is this behaviour? And how do I get the object from the postMessage
in the addListener without it getting held?

```js
function temp(){
    var globalObject = `var globalObject = domObj; `;
    var scriptHtml = [
      globalObject,
      `var obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(globalObject));`,
      `console.log("Obj in DOM",obj);`,
      `window.postMessage(obj)`,
    ].join("");

    s.innerHTML = scriptHtml;

    document.body.appendChild(s);

var obj = {};
    window.addEventListener(
      "message",
      function (event) {
        // We only accept messages from ourselves
        if (event.source != window) return;
        if (event.data) {
          obj = event.data;
          // console.log("Obj in Content.js ", obj);
          // port.postMessage(event.data);
        }
      },
      false
    );
return obj;
}
```

The "content.js" script is called from "background.js"

background.js

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    console.log(tabId, changeInfo, tab);
    if (changeInfo.status == 'complete') {
        Utils.executeScriptUsingTabId(tabId, 'content.js').catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
});
```

manifest.json

```json
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Ext",
    "description": "My Extension",
    "version": "5.0",
    "icons": {
        "128": "images/icon.png"
    },
    "externally_connectable": {
        "matches": ["*://*.example.com/*", "*://localhost/*"]
    },
    "permissions": [
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "tabs",
        "http://*/*",
        "https://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "page": "background.html"
    },
    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "My Extension",
        "default_icon": "images/icon.png",
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "web_accessible_resources": ["images/*.png", "helpers/*.js"]
}
```

content.js

```js
console.time("start");

import getPageVar from "./contentScripts/getPageVar";
import getPageVarFunc from "./contentScripts/getPageVarFunc";
import getAdsDotTxt from "./contentScripts/adsDotTxtResponse";
import $ from "jquery";
import Utils from "./libs/utils.js";

let adsDotTxtResponse = false;

if (!adsDotTxtResponse) {
  console.log("No data");
  getAdsDotTxt();
  adsDotTxtResponse = true;
}
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (
  { command, data },
  sender,
  sendResponse
) {
  try {
    switch (command) {
      case "getPageVar":
        sendResponse({ success: true, data: getPageVar(data.pageVar) });
        break;
      case "getPageVarFunc":
        sendResponse({ success: true, data: getPageVarFunc(data.pageVar) });
        break;
      case "setPrebidHandlers":
        console.log("Case SetPrebidHandlers");
        console.log(prebidEventHandlersSet);
        if (!prebidEventHandlersSet) {
          setPrebidHandlers();
          prebidEventHandlersSet = true;
        }
        sendResponse({ success: true, data: "Script executed" });
        break;
      case "getAdsDotTxt":
        console.log("send ads.txt response");
        if (!adsDotTxtResponse) {
          console.log("No data");
          getAdsDotTxt();
          adsDotTxtResponse = true;
          sendResponse({ success: true, data: "Fetching ads.txt data" });
        } else {
          console.log("Sending Data");
          sendResponse({
            success: true,
            data: getPageVarFunc(
              'document.getElementById("_My_adsDotTxt").innerText'
            ),
          });
        }
        break;
      case "scrollAdToScreen":
        const status = Utils.scrollElementToScreen($(`div[id='${data.id}']`));
        sendResponse({ success: status, data: { status } });
        break;
      case "highlightAds":
        Utils.borderifyAd(data.isMy);
        sendResponse({ success: true, data: { status: true } });
        break;
      case "adUnitReporting":
        Utils.getAdUnitReporting(data.isMy, data.toDate, data.fromDate);
        sendResponse({ success: true, data: { status: true } });
        break;
      case "appendAndReloadUrl":
        Utils.appendAndReloadURL(data.param);
        sendResponse({ success: true, data: { status: true } });
        break;
    }
  } catch (e) {}
  return true;
});
```

Comment: Your question doesn't show how the content script is declared/executed. Without seeing it we have to guess. If you have `all_frames: true` then it would explain the behavior you've described: each frame runs an instance of the content script which inserts the DOM script. Frames are created and loaded by the page after a small pause which you saw.

Comment: @wOxxOm Content script is executed/called from background.js. "all_frames": true is not declared in manifest. Also can you share some docs or references or your knowledge which could help me understand the picture.

Comment: @wOxxOm I have shared more code details. Let me know if that helps you get a lead. Also I am not executing allFrames: true anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. Looks like `status: 'complete'` in chrome.tabs.onUpdated is reported several times so your content script is injected each time and registers a new onMessage listener.

Try checking if the content script is already running by sending a special message like `ping` for which your onMessage should return `true`, for example:

background.js:

```js
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener((tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if (changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabId, 'ping', {frameId: 0}, ok => {
      if (chrome.runtime.lastError || !ok) {
        Utils.executeScriptUsingTabId(tabId, 'content.js').catch(console.log);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

content.js:

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (
  { command, data },
  sender,
  sendResponse
) {
  try {
    switch (command) {
      case "ping":
        sendResponse(true);
        break;
//////////////////////
```